# How to handle click event of link button inside gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview with some link buttons. What i am trying to do is when i click on link button, two buttons i.e. (Export to CSV and Export To Excel) will be shown.
But when i am clicking on any link button, nothing is happening...
Heres my code...

Gridview:

```
   <asp:GridView ID="grd_ComplaintCount" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
               CellPadding="4" EnableModelValidation="True" ForeColor="#333333" 
               GridLines="None">
               <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
               <Columns>

                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Complaint">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbtn_TotalComplaint" CommandName="Total"
                                Text='<%#Bind("TotalComplaint") %>' CommandArgument="Total"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                   </asp:TemplateField>                       

                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Open Complaint">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbtn_TotalOpenComplaint" CommandName="Open"
                                    Text='<%#Bind("TotalOpen") %>' CommandArgument="Open"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                   </asp:TemplateField>                       

                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Closed Complaint">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbtn_TotalCloseComplaint" CommandName="Closed"
                                    Text='<%#Bind("TotalClose") %>' CommandArgument="Closed"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                   </asp:TemplateField> 

                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Reassigned Complaint">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbtn_TotalReassignedComplaint" CommandName="Reassign"
                                    Text='<%#Bind("TotalMemberReAssign") %>' CommandArgument="Reassigned"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                   </asp:TemplateField>                        

                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Observation Complaint">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbtn_TotalObservationComplaint" CommandName="Obeservation"
                                    Text='<%#Bind("TotalObservation") %>' CommandArgument="Observation"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                   </asp:TemplateField>                        

               </Columns>
               <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
               <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
               <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
               <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
               <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
               <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
           </asp:GridView>
```

And this is my code..

```
Protected Sub grd_ComplaintCount_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles grd_ComplaintCount.RowCommand
        ComplaintCount_Detail(e.CommandArgument)

        If e.CommandName = "Total" Or e.CommandName = "Open" Or e.CommandName = "Closed" Or e.CommandName = "Reassign" Or e.CommandName = "Obeservation" Then
            btnexptocsv.Visible = True
            btnexptoexcel.Visible = True
        End If

    End Sub
```

I know i have done some mistakes...

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this in C# or VB? Because the back end code seems to be VB

Answer (score 0):

1.Change `asp:LinkButton` markup and specify `CommandName`

```
commandname="Select" text='<%# Eval("MEO_NR") %>'>
```

2.Create a `RowCommandEvent`

```
OnRowCommand="GVActiveMEOs_OnRowCommand"
```

Code-behind

```
Protected Sub gridview1_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    Dim meonum As String = DirectCast(e.CommandSource, LinkButton).CommandArgument 
End Sub
```

Always remember that the clicked row is not a `SelectedRow` unless you specify the `CommandName` as `CommandName="Select"`